# Law of a Random variable times and indicator

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have a simple question please.

I have a random variable $X$ defined on the real axis, what is the law of $X 1_{X\ge a}$ or in general $X 1_{X\in A}$, with $A$ being a subset of the real axis? What is the difference to the law of $X|X\in A$? $1$ denote the indicator function.

What is the law if $X$ is a $N$-dimensional random vector and $A$ a rectangle in $R^N$?

Many thanks,
Pier

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For $t > 0$, we have $X(\omega)1_{\{X\ge a\}}(\omega) < t\;$ if and only if $X(\omega) < t$ or $X(\omega) < a$.

For $t \le 0$, we have $X(\omega)1_{\{X\ge a\}}(\omega) < t\;$ if and only if $X(\omega) < t$ and $X(\omega) \ge a$.

On other hand, if $\Pr(X\ge a) > 0,\;$ we have
$$ \Pr(X < t \mid X \ge a) = \frac{\Pr(X<t, X\ge a)}{\Pr(X\ge a)}. $$